# When and why should I use attr.Factory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-attrs

When and why should I use `attr.ib(default=attr.Factory(list))` over `attr.ib(default=[])`?

From the [docs](http://attrs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html) I see that a Factory is used to generate a new value, which makes sense if you are using a lambda expression with inputs; however, I do not understand why you would use it if you are simply generating an empty list.

What am I missing here?

Comment: `default=[]` generates *an* empty list. One. Everyone has to share.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You want to *avoid* using mutable objects as defaults. If you used `attr.ib(default=[])`, what is generated is an `__init__` method using that list object as a keyword argument default:

```
def __init__(self, foo=[]):
    self.foo = foo
```

Default values for arguments are created **once**, at definition time. They are not re-evaluated each time you call the method. Any mutations to that object are then *shared across all instances*. See ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument).

Using the `attr.Factory()` approach however, the default is set to a sentinel, and when the argument is left as the sentinel value, *in the function itself* is the value then replaced with the result of calling the factory. This is equivalent to:

```
def __init__(self, foo=None):
    if foo is None:
        foo = []
    self.foo = foo
```

So now a new list object is created, per instance.

A quick demo demonstrating the difference:

```
>>> import attr
>>> @attr.s
... class Demo:
...     foo = attr.ib(default=[])
...     bar = attr.ib(default=attr.Factory(list))
...
>>> d1 = Demo()
>>> d1.foo, d1.bar
([], [])
>>> d1.foo.append('d1'), d1.bar.append('d1')
(None, None)
>>> d1.foo, d1.bar
(['d1'], ['d1'])
>>> d2 = Demo()
>>> d2.foo, d2.bar
(['d1'], [])
```

Because `demo.foo` is using a shared list object, changes made to it via `d1.foo` are visible, immediately, under any other instance.

When we use `inspect.getargspec()` to take a look at the `Demo.__init__` method, we see why:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getargspec(Demo.__init__)
ArgSpec(args=['self', 'foo', 'bar'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=(['d1'], NOTHING))
```

The default value for `foo` is the very same list object, with the appended `'d1'` string still there. `bar` is set to a sentinel object (here using `attr.NOTHING`; a value that makes it possible to use `Demo(bar=None)` without that turning into a list object):

```
>>> print(inspect.getsource(Demo.__init__))
def __init__(self, foo=attr_dict['foo'].default, bar=NOTHING):
    self.foo = foo
    if bar is not NOTHING:
        self.bar = bar
    else:
        self.bar = __attr_factory_bar()
```

Comment: `inspect.getargspec` is missing on python 3.11, the alternatives seem to be `inspect.getfullargspec` or `inspect.signature`.