# Different objects are preserving the state using attrs

Tags: python, oop, python-attrs

I'm making some experiments using [attrs](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/), but I'm experiencing some unexpected behaviors in the following code:

I created a class as this one:

```
@define
class User:
    name = field()
    errors = field(default=[])

    def compute_errors(self, error):
        self.errors.append(error)
```

Then I run the following script:

```
user1 = User(name="Miguel")

user1.compute_errors("Error 1")

user2 = User(name="Diogo")

print(user1)
print(user2)
```

The output is:

```
User(name='Miguel', errors=['teste'])
User(name='Diogo', errors=['teste'])
```

This is completely strange to me since `user1` and `user2` should be different objects. I've been reading the documentation but I'm not identifying any thing that mentions this. There's any explanation on that?

**Update 1**

I completely understand the explanation provided in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument). However, I can't understand why this is applied to class attributes too. If I don't use attrs it works as expected. The errors list is empty in the instantiation of `user2`.

**Update 3**

I just find the answer to my question in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44141104/when-and-why-should-i-use-attr-factory)

Comment: What are the "unexpected behaviors"? ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Comment: @Pexers I would expect that the device list was empty for user2 since it's a different object.